# Android Studio logcat BUG spamming java.io.IOException: Connection refused

Tags: android, debugging, logcat, android-logcat

In Android Studio when phone is connected for debugging logcat keeps spamming this error:

```
06-27 00:17:17.440     947-2476/? E/UsbDebuggingManager﹕ Communication error:
java.io.IOException: Connection refused
        at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connectLocal(Native Method)
        at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connect(LocalSocketImpl.java:290)
        at android.net.LocalSocket.connect(LocalSocket.java:130)
        at com.android.server.usb.UsbDebuggingManager.listenToSocket(UsbDebuggingManager.java:75)
        at com.android.server.usb.UsbDebuggingManager.run(UsbDebuggingManager.java:111)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

It's really anoying and it makes very difficult to debug.

Comment: Are you debugging on a real device or on an emulator?

Comment: Most Android devices are spammy. That's what the filter configuration in logcat is for. The logs originate on the device. It's not a bug in Android Studio.

Comment: @GeorgeD It's a real device and it's connected with a cable not bluetooth,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter this out of logcat using the Filter Configuration dropdown box to the right-hand side of the search box.

[image: Filter config location on screen]

Then enter a Log Tag regex:

[image: Log tag regex]

For my Nexus 5, I'm using this tag regex to suppress the spammy logs: `^(?!WifiStateMachine|ConnectivityService|ConnectivityManager)`

Comment: Looking at your original post, it seems like you want to get rid of the `UsbDebuggingManager` logging. Just try a few things, see what works for you.

Comment: Okay will try when I get home.